# Confused by the explanation of beta reduction of lambda calculus on wikipedia.

Tags: lambda-calculus

On [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) wikipedia article, there is an explanation of lambda calculus.

In the section of `Beta reduction`, there is an `Omega` example, which says `Omega = (lambda x.xx)(lambda x.xx)`, which

> reduces to itself in a single beta reduction, and therefore the
>   reduction process will never terminate.

At first, I thought the `(lambda x.xx)` means a function `f(x) = x * x`, but it seems the two `(lambda x.xx)`s in definition of `Omega` means an `application`. If it can reduce to itself, does that mean the `xx` in `(lambda x.xx)` actually is an `application`?  So the first lambda term in the definition of `Omega` actually means: **Give me something and I will apply it to itself** ? So the `Omega` means:

Give me `Give me something and I will apply it to itself` and I will apply it to itself, so it will reduce to:

Apply `Give me something and I will apply it to itself` to `Give me something and I will apply it to itself`,

and so it will becomes:

Give me `Give me something and I will apply it to itself` and I will apply it to itself.

That is the first process again, so never terminate.

Am I right?
If I am, I am wondering why this `(lambda x.xx)` term was not written as `(lambda x.(xx))` so it will be clearer.

Comment: Here's a tutorial for how to typeset math on this site: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020. (Allows you to have proper  symbols like $\lambda$ and $\Omega$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your thoughts is right. What isn't quite right is where you say that $\Omega$ means "Give me ...". The things that start with "Give me" are the $\lambda$ expressions. $\Omega=(\lambda x.xx)(\lambda x.xx)$ isn't a lambda expression, it's an application (just as $xx$ is, as you rightly deduced). It's the application of `Give me something and I will apply it to itself` to `Give me something and I will apply it to itself` (that is, to itself). This application reduces to itself.

On your question about why the application isn't enclosed in parentheses, [the notation section of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Notation) says that this is done "to keep the notation of lambda expressions uncluttered".

Comment: Thanks for your correction. I feel I can understand it better now. :smile: